# Pandas division (.div) with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have something similar to this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2, 10, size = (5, 2)))
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1, 'A'), (2, 'A'), (4, 'B'), 
           (5, 'B'), (8, 'B')])
df.index.names = ['foo', 'bar']
df.columns = ['count1', 'count2']
df
```

which gives:

```
       count1 count2
foo bar     
1   A    6     7
2   A    2     9
4   B    6     7
5   B    4     6
8   B    5     6
```

I also have a list of totals -obtained from somewhere else- by the same 'foo' index:

```
totals = pd.DataFrame([2., 1., 1., 1., 10.])
totals.index = [1, 2, 4, 5, 8]
totals.index.names = ['foo']
totals
```

which gives:

```
     0
foo 
1    2
2    1
4    1
5    1
8    10
```

How can I divide all the columns of *df* (*count1* and *count2*) by the the foo number that is in *totals*? (hence, i need to match by the 'foo' number)

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501510/divide-entire-pandas-multiindex-dataframe-by-dataframe-variable), which looks like it should do the trick, but I couldn't figure it out.

I tried

```
df.div(totals, axis = 0)
```

and changing the *level* option in *div*, but no success.

As always, thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have time to go into a more detailed answer. Does the following link help you out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940753/aligning-dataframes-with-same-columns-different-index-levels

Comment: this is a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501510/divide-entire-pandas-multiindex-dataframe-by-dataframe-variable

Comment: Hi, I checked those answers and tried with options level = 0 or level = 'foo', but it doesn't work. Roman Pekar's answer below works, but I don't see understand why.

Answer (score 7):

try:

```
df.div(totals[0],axis='index',level='foo')

         count1  count2
foo bar                
1   A       1.0     4.5
2   A       4.0     8.0
4   B       5.0     9.0
5   B       5.0     5.0
8   B       0.9     0.5
```

also:

```
totals = pd.DataFrame([2., 1., 1., 1., 10.])
totals.index = [[1, 2, 4, 5, 8],['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']]
totals.index.names = ['foo','bar']
totals
           0
foo bar      
1   A     2.0
2   A     1.0
4   B     1.0
5   A     1.0
8   B    10.0

df[['count1','count2']].div(totals[0],axis='index')
         count1  count2
foo bar                
1   A       1.0     4.5
2   A       4.0     8.0
4   B       5.0     9.0
5   A       NaN     NaN
    B       NaN     NaN
8   B       0.9     0.5
```

Comment: multi level index divide.

Answer (score 3):

Using `values` list from `totals[0]` works:

```
df.div(totals[0].values, axis=0)
```

But it doesn't take Index from `totals` into account. Don't know why this does not work:

```
df.div(totals[0], level=0, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitely works! I'd love to know why the other options don't work though

Comment: ``totals[0]`` takes out an existing level so saying ``level=0`` makes it broadcast on a particular level; the reason using just ``totals`` doesn't work is it has all of the levels to begin with.

Comment: adding `.values` made the difference in my `.div()` situation.  Thanks!