# Multiply Series by distributing across MultiIndex levels

Tags: python, pandas

This is a MultiIndex version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523370/pandas-division-div-with-multiindex).

Consider a `DataFrame` of sales figures:

```
sales = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2008,2008,2008,2008,2009,2009,2009,2009], 
                  'flavour':['strawberry','strawberry','banana','banana',
                  'strawberry','strawberry','banana','banana'],
                  'day':['sat','sun','sat','sun','sat','sun','sat','sun'],
                  'sales':[10,12,22,23,11,13,23,24]})
sales = sales.set_index(['year','flavour','day'])
>>> sales
year  flavour     day
2008  strawberry  sat    10
                  sun    12
      banana      sat    22
                  sun    23
2009  strawberry  sat    11
                  sun    13
      banana      sat    23
                  sun    24
```

Now I want to multiply each figure by a different number depending on the year *and* the day, stored as a `Series`:

```
>>> sales = pd.DataFrame([[2008, 'sat', 0], [2008, 'sun', 1], [2009, 'sat', 2], [2009, 'sun', 3]])
>>> sales = sales.set_index([0, 1])
          2
0    1     
2008 sat  0
     sun  1
2009 sat  2
     sun  3
```

Is there a neat way to multiply each figure from `sales` by its associated element of `mul`? This is a very common operation in SQL.

Comment: yes its the same question; use mul with a level argument

Comment: The confusion might be that `sales` is (unnecessarily) a DataFrame, and I believe this only works on Series. Use `.squeeze()` to convert like so: `sales.squeeze().mul(mul, level=2)`

Comment: `sales['sales'].mul(mul, level=2)` would also work

Comment: @DanAllan Does this work with multiple levels? In my real scenario, `mul` also has a multi-index and I always get `Join on level between two MultiIndex objects us ambiguous`

Comment: @DanAllan you should make that an answer! (I think that joining on two levels in a MI is fixed in master (0.14) / where not ambiguous...)

Comment: pretty sure this should work in master/0.14 (may be a bit tricky < 0.14 as the joining is a problem - it can be done but you have to jump thru some hoops), see here: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/basics.html#matching-broadcasting-behavior, and here: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#enhancements

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect the fact that it's really about MultiIndexed Series on both sides of the join. Didn't realise that was important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are defining `sales` for each side of the multiplicand. So defining the 2nd part as `m` (and naming the levels of the index).

```
In [28]: m = pd.DataFrame([[2008, 'sat', 0], [2008, 'sun', 1], [2009, 'sat', 2], [2009, 'sun', 3]],columns=['year','day','value']).set_index(['year','day'])

In [29]: m
Out[29]: 
          value
year day       
2008 sat      0
     sun      1
2009 sat      2
     sun      3

[4 rows x 1 columns]
```

Simply merge

```
In [30]: x = pd.merge(sales.reset_index(),m.reset_index(),on=['year','day'])
```

Set

```
In [31]: x['sales_value'] = x['sales']*x['value']
```

Reset the index

```
In [32]: x.set_index(['year','flavour','day'])
Out[32]: 
                     sales  value  sales_value
year flavour    day                           
2008 strawberry sat     10      0            0
     banana     sat     22      0            0
     strawberry sun     12      1           12
     banana     sun     23      1           23
2009 strawberry sat     11      2           22
     banana     sat     23      2           46
     strawberry sun     13      3           39
     banana     sun     24      3           72

[8 rows x 3 columns]
```

This is being worked on, but is still an open issue. see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5645). The soln actually is simply to embed this soln in the broadcast numerics (.e.g mul/add ...).

Answer (score 0):

The confusion might be that sales is (unnecessarily) a DataFrame, and I believe this only works on Series. Use .squeeze() to convert like so:

```
sales.squeeze().mul(mul, level=2)
```